# Apologies to the site

Tags: discussion

It has come to my attention that I may be rude and inconsiderate (likened to a notoriously and self-confessed rude user on Physics.SE) - I wish to assure people that it has and is never my intention to be rude or inconsiderate.

So, I apologise if I have ever been that way to any member.

I will step back from my participation in this site - just to do the 'background' duties, unless my participation here is also of concern.

Comment: Well, have made a final bounty - it seems even using these do not work. Best wishes with the site.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the one that should apologize. I seemed to have implied that you were being rude (when I posted a message on chat), and that could not be further from the truth. You've been considerate to new users (all users, really), and have contributed an enormous amount of knowledge to this site and other sites on SE. I never meant to imply (When I compared you to that user) that you were mean, rude or callous or advocated that kind of behavior.

> unless my participation here is also of concern.

I'm actually very concerned - I think we'd all love for you to continue the active role you have on HSM!

Answer (score 5):

Consider brushing off whatever inspired this post into distant memory. I am at a total loss as to how you could be construed as being the person that you describe. While I have not posted much here (work teaching has consumed me), I have taken the time to read every single thing here since conception including all of your behavior. You are one of the most polite, levelheaded, and courteous posters that I have ever seen anywhere. You might consider just relegating whatever trivial chatter caused you to feel maligned as being misinterpreted web transmissions, knowing that this can happen.

If you cannot relegate this to misinterpretation, then consider just ignoring whatever spawned this event and continue safe in mind that you are not the person that you describe here.